How to reinstall new Ubuntu 24.4 on the old version 9.0?
I have an old Ubuntu v.9.0 on my desktop. I want to reinstall a new version. Browsers don't work. I was told to download a new version on a flash drive and reinstall. Can you please advise the link to download the new version that I can use to reinstall on my desktop? Do I need to do anything with the old version? How to do it. I don't need any data from the old system. I need

http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/24.04/release/xubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso ... See at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1533388/cant-boot-ubuntu-24-04-after-a-fresh-install-multiple-grub-errors/1533424?noredirect=1#comment2697883_1533424

If system that old, Ubuntu probably too much system. Now more for newer systems. Better to use a lightweight flavor. I even found Kubuntu worked on older laptop even though more of a middle weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)

What are your system specs?

Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361769/what-options-do-i-have-to-upgrade-an-unsupported-i386-version-of-ubuntu-to-an-op/1361780#1361780

There is no Ubuntu v9; maybe you mean Ubuntu 8.10 which was the 9th release back in October 2008 but you tagged 9.04 or the 10th release. You don't specify product, as you can non-destructively re-install some Desktop systems, but not Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS, but you gave no useful clues as to your existing system so we can't advise. There is an answer here that is useful; and can be used with 24.04; but not with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop: https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way but it may NOT be what I'd use as I'd base it on details you didn't give
